# Dreamweaver CS6 nicer codes

Tags: dreamweaver, code-formatting, komodoedit

why is with Dreamweaver CS6 not possible to code nicely like Komodo Edit 7?

With DREAMWEAVER CS6 my code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test DW</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Main Heading</h1>
<p>Some body content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

With KOMODO EDIT 7 it looks this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test Komod Edit</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>Main Heading</h1>
                <p>Some body content.</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

How can I achieve the same effect with Dreamweaver?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Commands and select "Apply Source Formatting", this will apply indented formatting to all your code. If you only want to format a selection of code then use the "Apply Source Formatting to Selection" option below.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver Preferences (Ctrl or Cmd + U) > Code Format. There is also the Advanced Formatting menu which allows specific formatting for different languages (e.g. css vs javascript). If that's still not to your liking you tab while typing . . .

Comment: The Advanced Formatting requires me to setup each and every Tag one by one. I'm more likely looking a solution to do this task at once or automatically.